# ERC20 coin transaction not successful

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-design, erc-20, metamask

I called the `mint` function on a default coin to send some of my new coin to my METAMASK account but it looks like nothing was received. I can't tell what specifically could have gone wrong, so here's an image with all relevant information.

Thanks in advance for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not following [the ERC20 spec](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md). You need to follow the spec in order for Metamask to understand that you have tokens.

---

You have two issues with your current code.

Your first issue is that you do not have a `balanceOf` map. Metamask uses this mapping to display your balances.

The second is that you do not have a `totalSupply` variable that tracks the total supply of tokens.

Comment: clear, concise answer. Haven't implemented yet but really happy with your response. Thank you Shane